# Missing Function while using C++/CLI wrapper dll

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wrapper

I was writing a C++/CLI wrapper for using some umnmanaged C++ code in a visual basic project . This is the code

```
    #pragma once
    #include "E:\ARDUINO DLL\UnManagedSystemProfile\UnManagedSystemProfile\SystemProfile.h"
    #include "E:\ARDUINO DLL\UnManagedSystemProfile\UnManagedSystemProfile\SystemProfile.cpp"

using namespace System;

namespace MSystemProfile {

public ref class SystemProfile

{
            SysProfileInterface * System;

public:
    SystemProfile();
 enum class  ConversionDirection:int
    {
        FORWARD,
        REVERSE
    };
    enum class MemoryUnits:int
    {
        BYTE,KB,MB,GB
    };

    double getVolume();
    void   setVolume(float volume);
    void   setScreenBrightness(int brightnessvalue);
    int    getCurrentBatteryLife();
    bool   isLowOnPower();
    bool   isCharged();
    bool   isCharging();
    bool CheckFreeSpace(LPCTSTR lpDirectoryName);
    DWORD64 getFreeSpaceAvailable(LPCTSTR lpDirectoryname);
    DWORDLONG totalVirtualMemory();
    DWORDLONG usedVirtualMemory();
    SIZE_T myVirtualMemoryUse();
    DWORDLONG totalRam();
    DWORDLONG usedRam();
    SIZE_T myRamUse();



    float BtoKB(float   data, MemoryUnitConverter::ConversionDirection  direction);
    float BtoMB(float   data, MemoryUnitConverter::ConversionDirection  direction);
    float BtoGB(float  data, MemoryUnitConverter::ConversionDirection   direction);
    float KBtoMB(float data, MemoryUnitConverter::ConversionDirection   direction);
    float KBtoGB(float  data,MemoryUnitConverter::ConversionDirection   direction);
    float MBtoGB(float  data, MemoryUnitConverter::ConversionDirection   direction);

    float convertTo(MemoryUnitConverter::MemoryUnits sourceunit,MemoryUnitConverter::MemoryUnits destinationunit, float data);




};
}
```

In this there are two functions namely

```
bool CheckFreeSpace(LPCTSTR lpDirectoryName);
    DWORD64 getFreeSpaceAvailable(LPCTSTR lpDirectoryname);
```

When i built them and refrenced in a visual basic project the following error came

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8774.png)

It said that
**Error 3   'CheckFreeSpace' has a return type that is not supported or parameter types that are not supported.**

I understood that maybe VB.net does not support LPCTRSTR type but now how can i solve this problem.

Also another problem is that if C++/CLI supports **LPCTRSTR** then why not VB.net.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is a pointer type, either byte* or char* in C#.  But vb.net does not support pointers.  Change the argument type to String^, convert to a pointer with, say, Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni().

Answer (score 0):

The type LPCTSTR is a C/C++ type created by Microsoft for use in Windows API. Since C++/CLI is a C++ code, with managed extensions, it cans resolve LPCTSTR type without errors. VB.Net, however, is a managed code and cans "see" only managed types, which don't include LPCTSTR.

To pass parameters from/to unmanaged code, you may use the *MarshalAs* attribute. In VB.Net the function declaration would be:

```
<DllImport("<your's dll>", CharSet := CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError := true)>
 Friend Shared Function CheckFreeSpace(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPCStr)> lpDirectoryName as string) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)> Boolean;
```

You can read more information about marshaling [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke).

Comment: `LPCTSTR` = `const wchar_t*` under unicode. The problem doesn't lie in VB.NET being managed code, as C# would be able to see this function (with a `char*` parameter type), it lies in VB.NET not supporting pointer types at all. Anyway, you'd want to expose a `System::String^` for use from managed code. Use `marshal_context` or `PtrToStringChars` instead of P/Invoke under C++/CLI, it's easier and more efficient.

Comment: marshal_context

Answer (score 0):

I  solved the problem by taking the argument to the function as system::String and  as Hans said, marshalled it to std:: string using standard Marshall function given as a Microsoft example and called the c. Str() function in it to get a char*.  Also I changed my character set to multibyte to solve the problem.